# DateDiff with SQL Query

Tags: sql, datediff

I'm wondering if anyone might be able to point out the issue with the following code. In particular, the dateDiff part. What I'm trying to do is figure out the difference (in days) between sending an invoice and the deposit date. If the deposit date is null, I want to use today's date. Simple, I'd have thought...

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT i.dateSent
    , i.dateDeposit
    , i.invoiceID
    , i.gstValue
    , i.invoiceValue AS invoiceTotal
    , p.projectValue
    , i.invoiceNumber
    , p.projectName
    , p.projectNumber
    , p.projectID
    , c.clientName
    , c.clientCode
    , c.clientID
    , DATEDIFF(i.dateSent, CASE WHEN i.dateDeposit IS Null Then GetDate() ELSE i.dateDeposit) as numbDays

FROM cms_invoices i

LEFT JOIN cms_projects p ON p.projectID = i.projectID
LEFT JOIN cms_clients c ON p.clientID = c.clientID

ORDER BY i.dateDeposit ASC, c.clientName ASC
");
```

At this stage the result is no result. The dateDiff line breaks the query. Arg.

Thanks,
@rrFive

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're missing an `END`:

```
... DATEDIFF(i.dateSent, 
    CASE
        WHEN i.dateDeposit IS NULL
            THEN GetDate()
        ELSE i.dateDeposit
     END) AS numbDays
```